# package co.flightrecorder.android does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, compilation, package, emulation

Could anybody help me to fix instalation error:

> Error:(35, 33) error: package co.flightrecorder.android does not exist

This error occurs **when I compile the application** while I trying to run the application in the emulator in android studio.

I would like to show this issue in a [GIF animation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4BR8IK9eGCAZDdkY21WU2FKeEU/view).

Answer (score 0):

I have decided it that way:
- in build.gradle add row in dependencies: **compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')***
// this not working: compile fileTree(include: ['.jar'], dir: 'libs')
- make folder **myapplication/app/libs**
- move **flightrecorder.jar** file to myapplication/app/libs
- do SyncGradle
- build project and run emulator
:)